# Enum for possible values of HyperLink.Target

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

Maybe kind of a noob .NET question, but is there an enum that represents the possible values for HyperLink.Target (e.g. "_blank", "_top", etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no ready-made enum. Probably because (besides the special values starting with _) target can contain the name of a specific frame where it has to open the document

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built-in enum for this in the .NET Framework. You have to create it yourself. :)